# upstart - chdir does not recognize variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart

chdir stanza in an upstart conf file doesn't seem to recognize a variable - am I missing something or is there a workaround?

```
env MHOME=/home/foo/bar
chdir $MHOME
```

getting this error:

```
unable to change working directory: No such file or directory
```

here's a complete upstart conf file, using export instead of env:

```
$ cat /etc/init/foo.conf 
description "foo"

start on runlevel [23]
stop on shutdown

export FOO=/tmp

chdir $FOO
#chdir /tmp

console log

exec python -m SimpleHTTPServer

respawn
```

this gives the following error in syslog:

```
 kernel: [727103.302734] init: Failed to spawn foo main process: unable to change working directory: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

env only applies to exec and script stanzas. Try this:

```
env FOO=/tmp

script
    chdir $FOO
    exec python -m SimpleHTTPServer
end script
```

Comment: this worked for me: in particular using the script / end script directive

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use:

```
export MHOME=/home/foo/bar
```

I don't know very well command env, but it seems not what you need.

From info env:

> ## 23.2 `env': Run a command in a modified environment
>
> `env' runs a command with a modified environment.  Synopses:
>
> ```
>  env [OPTION]... [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARGS]...]
>  env
> ```

Comment: export didnt help too, chdir still fails :(

Comment: Wait, are you sure you write the correct directory name?

export i'm sure that works.

try in a shell: `export MHOME=/home/foo/bar`
and then
`cd $MHOME`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't try again immediately. I just tried and it still doesn't work. It works in a shell (bash). Can you try it out once and see if it works for you without any errors in syslog? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Could you please write here the conf file?

Comment: In this context, `env` is not a shell command but an upstart stanza.